# Can Random Variable model behavior over time?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Can a random variable be used to model a quantity that changes over time? I know of differential equations that are used to model such, but can random variables model such behaviour?

I can visualize a differential equation say of velocity as that value changing over time, I can't seem to visualize random variables and probability distributions, what do they represent and visualize physically?

Comment: Random variable is a function over a space with probability measure. If you want it to change with time take a map from an interval to the space of such functions, you'll get a time dependent random "variable".

Comment: Random variables take… random values. They can only model in a probabilistic way. Why do you ask this question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I asked can they be used to model behaviour over time, not necessarily just ones which are not random

Comment: @kauray: what ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust for example can random variables be used to model velocity?

Comment: You may take a look at stochastic process, or even stochastic integral.

Comment: @kauray: sorry, your answers are not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. They are called *stochastic processes* and not only depend on the sample space but also a time indexing set:
$$X:T\times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$$
where, often, $T=[0,\infty)$. For each outcome $\omega \in \Omega$, we may study the *sample path* $X_t(\omega)$ as a function from $T\to \mathbb{R}$ for another viewpoint. Loosely speaking, if the process is *stationary* then the distribution does not change over time. This is common in some physical modeling.

Answer (score 0):

Another point of view. You could introduce time dependent random variables by specifying parameters as functions changing over time.